# Last word in something

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

Dictionaries give **be the last word in something** as the correct construction, but in the following sentence

[The ICC World Cup remains the last word on cricket’s hierarchy.](https://www.thehindu.com/opinion/editorial/a-cup-to-win/article27297832.ece)

**"on"** is used. Is that correct?

Comment: We always say *That's my last word **on** the subject*, but *That's the last word **in** luxury*. Noting the huge shift in preference to ***on*** rather than ***in*** with [*last word **on/in** the matter*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=last+word+on+the+matter%2Clast+word+in+the+matter&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clast%20word%20on%20the%20matter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clast%20word%20in%20the%20matter%3B%2Cc0) over the past half-century, I think maybe the latter is something of a (highly metaphorical) "frozen form".

Answer (score 1):

It appears the headline writer is mixing up:

> ... is the last word in ...  (meaning "epitome")
>
> The Rolls Royce is the last word in luxury.

With

> ... have the last word on ... (have the deciding opinion)
>
> The Supreme court has the last word on the constitution.

So, it looks like an error to me.

Comment: Actually, I'm not so sure. The *specific* cited context is something of a cross between the two usages. The ICC World Cup could be seen as "having the final say" regarding which team tops the hierarchy (so ***on*** is credible), but it could also be understood as saying that the ICC World Cup represents the "epitome, embodiment" of that hierarchy (so ***in*** is credible). To confuse things even more - assuming you'd accept changing ***remains*** to ***retains***, which preposition would you *then* favour? Does that verb change make a difference? *Should* it?